# why parseInt converts value to infinity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, parseint

i am doing this :

```
var s = '50';

var a = parseInt(s);

console.log(a); //prints 50

console.log(_.isFinite(a)); //prints false
```

so why parseInt changes a into infinite when a = 50?

Comment: I'm getting `true` when passing `50`. What version are you using? Btw, this does not seem to have anything to do with `parseInt` - it yields the number `50` just as expected.

Comment: Why are you calling isFinite method on `_`? In general, you should supply the radix argument to parseInt when using it; just to be safe.

Comment: why do you have '_.'. is that a typo

Comment: @Pratik: most likely a library (such as [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isFinite)).

Comment: why is tht _ is used??

Comment: @DarkCthulhu, Pratik, NeelBhatt: Because [it's an Underscore method](http://underscorejs.org/#isFinite)?

Comment: Using `window.isFinite()` should be the same shouldn't it?

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: it's different - `_.isFinite` only allows string representations of numbers and numbers, while `isFinite()` calls `Number()` on the argument, making (say) `false` result in `true` while that wouldn't be true for the Underscore version of it.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: It handles string literals a bit differently. It also does `parseFloat` not only `ToNumber` - differences can be seen on the empty string for example.

Comment: on jsfiddle i get my desired result : http://jsfiddle.net/TjD2r/

Comment: i need to look through my project..

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the code provided OR underscore.  Same code returns true for me in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DanielBank/U5akx/

Answer (score -1):

Try running this. I think your "_." before isFinite is the problem.

```
var s = '50';

var a = parseInt(s);

alert(a); //prints 50

alert(isFinite(a));//prints true
```

Comment: `_` is the [Underscore library](http://underscorejs.org), hence the "underscore.js" tag.